# 2001 Toyota Sequoia horn works sometimes

Tags: toyota, horn, sequoia

2001 Toyota Sequoia horn works sometimes. I changed the fuse. Is it possible that the relay is bad? How would I know?

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!

Comment: Are the connections to the horn loose?Check the connecting wires it should be firm

Comment: @Pᴀᴜʟsᴛᴇʀ2 thanks, might be in over my head though!

Answer (score 1):

You will have to test the system logically :

1 supply - is it intermittent

2 switch for operation

3 supply to relay

4 relay

5 supply to horn

6 horn

7 earthing of horn but you can do this first as it is a common issue.

For testing use a test lamp or multimeter : lamp probably better in this case as it gives a more "visual" response when power is there...

Comment: This is a great list of things to check. How would the OP go about checking any single part you've mentioned? A list of bad parts is great, but instructions would make this answer great!